# How to Delete Additional build files from the Project Solution in visual studio

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

How to delete `additional build files` from the project solution in Visual Studio?

I am forced to clear this files everytime manually when I want to give my executable program to anyone

[image: my compilation]

Any solution?

I am using `C#` and `C++`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simple

1. Right click at the project
   [image]
2. Go to build events. From there you can play with many things.
   [image]

Comment: thanks , i have made an program using system("del"); also to delete the files after 1 click
but seems like your way easier than me xD

Comment: glad that I can help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

These files are generated when the `.exe` is generated and you can't force VS to not `make` them.

Comment: Can i just move these files to another folder alone?

Comment: Not really because they will always be located at the location of the `.exe`. An alternative is that you can just send the `.exe` itself to your friend. Also, GitHub is a great option, because most email servers, such as Gmail, won't let you send executables.

Answer (score 0):

Upload your build to [github](https://github.com/).

Give your friend the link to the build repository.

Make your friend delete the files when they download the repo.

**To answer your question**: No, there is no way to prevent VS from automatically generating these build files. But there are ways to circumvent you from having to do the work, as I've stated above.